# Update Component after post new item to the Database

Tags: fetch, svelte, reload, sveltekit

I am playing around with Sveltekit and I am struggling a bit..

So my problem is, when I add something to the DB it works, but the new Item does not show in the list until i Refresh the page. My Code looks like:

**index.js**

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '$lib/db';

export const post = async ({ request}) => {

    const body = await request.json()
    console.log(body)

    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;
    const einkaufszettel = db.collection('Einkaufszettel')

    await einkaufszettel.insertOne({
        name: body.newArticle
    });

    const einkaufsliste = await einkaufszettel.find().toArray();

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: {
            einkaufsliste
        }
    };

}


export const get = async () => {

    const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
    const db = dbConnection.db;
    const einkaufszettel = db.collection('Einkaufszettel')
    
    const einkaufsliste = await einkaufszettel.find().toArray();

    console.log(einkaufsliste)

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: {
            einkaufsliste,
        }
    };

}
```

and the Script of **index.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Title from '$lib/title.svelte'
    export let einkaufsliste = []
    let newArticle = ''

    const addArticle = async () => {

        const res = await fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                newArticle
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        fetchArticles()
    }

    async function fetchArticles() {
        const res = await fetch('/')
        console.log(res.body)
    }

</script>
```

In the Network Preview Tab the new Item is already added to the List.

Comment: Are you trying to access the body from the fetch? If you are, you need to use `await res.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can [read here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects), you need to reassign the `einkaufsliste` after fetching the list of elements from the API.

You can do this in your `fetchArticles` method, like this:

```
async function fetchArticles() {
  einkaufsliste = await fetch('/')
}
```

Comment: Ok i found my errors with your help. While the index.js was in the root src Folder, i did not received the response body. Now i moved the index.js to /src/api and now i get the correct response body, is it a bug? After my POST fetch I update the var like einkaufsliste = data.einkaufsliste, simple as that and now it works perfect.

Comment: Regarding the location of the API, I don't know. That entirely depends on your entire project's folder structure and other setups.